# Can you, and if so, how, set a repeat rate for mouse buttons?

Tags: mouse

I have an external mouse, with programmable buttons. I'd like to set some of those buttons to repeat if I hold one of them down- similar to how keyboard keys repeat, but don't see where to do that.

Comment: Interesting question, but I'd instinctively say it can't be done [easily] as then how would you differentiate between holding the button down to drag something vs. run a repeat click?

Comment: Ideally, it's up to you to configure. For me, I'd leave right and left-click alone, and let my other buttons repeat.

Comment: I'm looking for this too. I use an IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0 with SteerMouse with back and forward buttons mapped to `cmd+[` and it repeats too quickly.

Comment: There are some auto-clicker apps [listed here](http://www.murgaa.com/auto-clicker-mac/) that might help, though it appears they mainly trigger on keyboard shortcuts rather than just holding down the mouse button. Caveat: I've never used or installed any of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a a product called [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/).  They have a feature called the  [Auto-Repeater](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/doc/#autorepeater_block) Building Block

> The Auto-Repeater building block provides a way to automatically
>   repeat events at a fixed rate.
>
> An Auto-Repeater building block has one ON/OFF input and one ON/OFF
>   output. While the input is ON, the output turns ON and OFF at a
>   predetermined rate.
>
> To configure an Auto-Repeater building block, enter the rate at which
>   it should turn its output ON and OFF. The rate can be given as the
>   number of repeats per second, or seconds per repeat.

(They provide an example on the page linked above)

[image]
[image]

Basically, if the Building Block detects an "on" state of an input (holding the button) it will auto repeat whatever you tell it to repeat at a set rate.

You will have to bypass the programming of the mouse and use this to program it.  I have done this with my Logitech MX Professional mouse and a second (Logitech) keyboard which I have reassigned keys to complex macros.

Controller Mate has an unlimited trial period that is limited to 10 "building blocks" meaning you can have a single work flow of 10 blocks or 5 flows of 2 blocks or whatever combination so long as it has no more than 10.  However, at $25, it's a very reasonable solution.