# How can I remap the left keypad keys of a Kinesis Freestyle keyboard on macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have a PC version of the USB Kinesis Freestyle keyboard. It've used these keyboards for years with my Macs and they work very well for me, but I have never used the block of keys along the left-hand side.

[image]

The <kbd>back</kbd>/<kbd>fwd</kbd> keys in particular would be ripe for use to control iTunes, but the problem is that pressing them generates <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>arrow</kbd> key sequences, and remapping <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>arrow</kbd> sequences would cause problems in applications that use <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>arrow</kbd> keys for editing functions.

Is there a way to change the character sequence that the Kinesis keyboard generates?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/284034/119271).  It's about programming mouse buttons, but the software should be able to reprogram the extra keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer linking to the "auto-repeater" software would have the unwanted result you mentioned of trying to remap the basic ⌘-arrow keys.

As I'm sure you know by now it's not possible to remap the keys on the Kinesis Freestyle keyboard as it's not programmable.

They answer this question in their FAQ on their website:
https://www.kinesis-ergo.com/support/technical-support/faqs-freestyle-keyboard/

*Disclaimer, I know this is 7 months old at this time but it's a top Google result and didn't have a proper answer*